# Sequelize for Node.js: cannot authenticate for postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am having issues with setting up the sequelize module for node.js.

First I set up a username and password in postgresql:

```
postgres=# CREATE USER testuser WITH PASSWORD 'test';
```

Here is my initialize code:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('testdb', 'testuser', 'test', {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5342,
    dialect: 'postgres'
});

sequelize.query('select * from mytbl').success(function(tbl){
    console.log('success');
});
```

However, when i run this short bit of code I get the following error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Failed to authenticate for PostgresSQL. Please double check your settings.
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong? If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What's in Postgres' log?

Comment: The logs in /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9-1-main.log doesn't seem to have anything in it at all related to the sequelize code

Comment: Try to connect to Postgres with the CLI client `psql` using the same connection info, e.g. `psql -h localhost -U testuser testdb`.

Comment: Hmm it looks like everything works fine when I connect in that way

Comment: @mathmonkey what happens if you try like this: `sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://testuser:test@localhost:5432/testdb', {
      dialect:  'postgres',
      protocol: 'postgres'
    })`

Comment: Still having the same issues unfortunately. I have tried using the 'pg' client for postgres before using those same connection details and everything works fine that way.

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Comment: No, I switched to using node-orm2 instead

Comment: @MikeSmithDev your suggestion worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This example worked when I changed the port to 5432.